# Unique array in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unique

I have this array

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (

                [id] => book
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => author
                        [1] => title
                        [2] => genre
                        [3] => price
                        [4] => publish_date
                        [5] => description
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => book
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => author
                        [1] => title
                        [2] => genre
                        [3] => price
                        [4] => publish_date
                        [5] => description
                    )

            )

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => library
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => room
                        [1] => room
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => library
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => book
                        [1] => book
                        [2] => book
                        [3] => book
                   )   
            )  
    )
```

And i want my output look like

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => library
                [name] => Array
                     (
                        [0] => room
                        [1] => room
                    )
                     (
                        [0] => book
                        [1] => book
                        [2] => book
                        [3] => book
                    )

            )

    )
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (

                [id] => book
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => author
                        [1] => title
                        [2] => genre
                        [3] => price
                        [4] => publish_date
                        [5] => description
                    )

            )
    }
```

I am trying to do that compare all id and name
if it have same id so unique it  get all the value [name] together
if it have same name and and same id unique them
Thank so much
I am trying to do that  but it only return with only unique id and it has warning  :
Undefined index: name

```
if (is_array($servico))
{
    foreach($servico as $data)
    {                              
        $result[$data['id']][] =  ($data['name']);                             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the new element is already in the array before adding it, so that you only get unique elements. And to prevent that warning about the undefined index, you need to initialize the element if it doesn't exist yet.

```
foreach ($servico as $data) {
    if (!isset($result[$data['id']])) {
        $result[$data['id']] = array();
    }
    if (!in_array($data['name'], $result[$data['id']])) {
        $result[$data['id']][] = $data['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you it is just what i want but it still with waring PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name

Comment: Are some of the elements of `$servico` missing the `name` element? That would cause this warning.

Comment: i dont really understand your quetion but i also have $data['atribut']

Comment: That warning means that when you access `$data['name']` there's no such element. And that can only happen if some of the elements of the input array are missing that key.

Comment: oh, some of my dont have $data['name'] . how can i do to make this not waring

Comment: I'm confused about your input. Did you post it correctly? It looks like it's two different arrays, not one array.

Comment: I'm getting really tired of helpless programmers here. My code shows how to use `isset()` to test whether an array element exists in `$result`, how hard is it to extrapolate that to what you need?\